# android using layout height 0dp in both child and parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to achieve the following:

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">    

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.42">

        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/ist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" <!-- GETTING ERROR : Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, probably intended for layout_width -->
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/Bkgd"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:stackFromBottom="true" />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/white" >

            <Button android:id="@+id/Btn"                
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/input_btn"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.58"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:columnWidth="30dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have marked in the above code where Android Studio shows error in layout.

Using above layout, I'm getting output as:

[image]

What changes should I make to have layout like first picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well had surprising difficulty with the linear layout so if you aren't apposed to relative layout this can do something similar.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.42">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutHolder"
            android:background="@color/Bkgd"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:stackFromBottom="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHolder"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:background="@android:color/white" >

            <Button android:id="@+id/Btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/input_btn"
                    android:background="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.58"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:columnWidth="30dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just make listview's height as wrap_content (because now 0 dp does not matter) and remove layout weight from listview and linearlayoutholder, and remove orientation (not needed) from relative layout

Answer (score 0):

Actually you've forgot to define orientation in Layout with weight 0.42.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.42"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

But I'm not sure if that will work with older APIs, so using of RelativeLayouts gives more stable result.

Answer (score 0):

Globally, you should avoid use nested weight (recommended by google and show like warning in Android Studio)

You can create your view with only one imbrication like this (Place the button before the linearlayout) :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.42">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/input_btn"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/Btn"
            android:background="@color/Bkgd"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:stackFromBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.58"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:columnWidth="30dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```